# Run mongostore in container with python3 script returns exit 126

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, docker, subprocess

I am trying to use `mongostore` command to restore my database by giving `gzip archive`.

Using the Python' `subprocess.check_output` method shown as below:

```py
# ...
# ...
subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'exec', mongoContId, 'mongostore', '--gzip',
'archive=' + targetWithFileName, '--db', DB_NAME])
```

- `mongoContId`: contain id of the container, that has obtained with a fuction.
- `DB_NAME`: constant name value of the database.

Result:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restore.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "restore.py", line 15, in main
    restoreMongo(args[0])
  File "restore.py", line 31, in restoreMongo
    subprocess.check_output(['docker', 'exec', mongoContId, 'mongostore', '--gzip', 'archive=' + targetWithFileName,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 415, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['docker', 'exec', '4c00a4964cdb', 'mongostore', '--gzip', 'archive=/opt/demo_2022-01-07_223628.gz', '--db', 'project-x']' returned non-zero exit status 126
```

But, If I run the command as bash command on cli:

- `docker exec 4c00a4964cdb mongorestore --gzip --archive=/opt/demo_2022-01-07_223628.gz --db project-x`

The result is:

```sh
...
...
022-01-12T09:03:18.485+0000 restoring indexes for collection project-x.sessions from metadata
2022-01-12T09:03:18.485+0000    index: &idx.IndexDocument{Options:primitive.M{"expireAfterSeconds":0, "name":"expireAt", "ns":"project-x.sessions", "v":2}, Key:primitive.D{primitive.E{Key:"expireAt", Value:1}}, PartialFilterExpression:primitive.D(nil)}
2022-01-12T09:03:18.486+0000    5757 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Where is the problem that I did wrong? Thanks!

> Docker version: 20.10.8
> Python version: 3.8.10
> MongoDB shell version v5.0.5

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is basic typo, I changed command from `mongostore` to `mongorestore`.

The second, I cannot run it with `check_output` method, so then, I used `run` method, and that solved the problem.